# How to join these two tables properly?

Tags: sqlite

I have these two tables

customers:

```
id | name                | address
---+---------------------+-------------------------
1  | company 1           | some address information
2  | company 2           | another address
3  | yet another company | no address here
```

orders:

```
id | customer_id | date
---+-------------+---------
1  | 2           | 20151209
2  | 2           | 20151211
3  | 3           | 20151210
4  | 1           | 20151223
```

Now I want to get a resulting table with **each customer** on the left and the amount of orders within an **arbitrary period of time** on the right.
For example, given this period to be 20151207 <= date <= 20151211, the resulting table should look like this:

```
name                | orders count
--------------------+-------------
company 1           | 0
company 2           | 2
yet another company | 1
```

*Note: date = 20151207 means the 7th of december 2015.*

How to join them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SELECT c.name, COUNT(CASE WHEN ((o.date BETWEEN 20151207 AND 20151211) OR (o.date ISNULL)) THEN o.customer_id END) AS "Total Sales" FROM customers AS c LEFT JOIN orders o ON c.id == o.customer_id GROUP BY c.name

Comment: typo - equals operator is = not ==

Comment: = and == are the same in sqlite I'm sure, it ran fine when I checked it in SqliteBrowser (see: http://sqlitebrowser.org)

Comment: true theyre the same on sqlite ( sqlite addition to standard sql )

Comment: Now I get a list with all customers (15 so far) on one column, and "1" for every row of the other column (except a 2 for one of them), but I only have 4 orders so far. Besides that I only want orders within an certain period of time

Comment: I've added a WHERE clause that will output between two given dates (you will need to supply these dynamically based upon what data you need to output). I don't see your behaviour but I don't have an exact copy of your database - I copied your sample in your question, and the output was exactly the same as your required output. If you're doing more work in SQLite you should look at the link I posted in my comment above as that will give you the syntax you need to build your own queries.

Comment: I've just checked and I can see the behaviour you describe if a company has no orders - your sample DB didn't have that so I couldn't check originally. I've amended my answer again. Please vote and accept if this is satisfactory.

Comment: Worked almost perfect this time, until I added the WHERE clause. Now when I add it, the resulting table only consists of those customers who have pending orders (two in this case). All others are gone again. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Sneedlewoods I've made another amendment, please try that.

Comment: This way customers which do have (any) orders, but none within the selected time span, are missing.

Comment: @Sneedlewoods Isn't that the behaviour you required?

Comment: Sorry, bad expression. I meant that those customers, which do have (any) orders, but none of them within the desired period of time, are missing, instead of being shown with 0 orders. Customers which don't have any orders at all are correctly shown with 0 orders.

Comment: @Sneedlewoods I've amended my SQL statement again, now the behaviour I get is:
1. Companies with orders within the date range have their order count totalled
2. Companies with orders outside the date range have "Total Sales" displayed as 0
3. Companies without any order records have "Total Sales" displayed as 0

Comment: Awesome! That's exactly how I wanted it. Thank you so much for your patience! :-)